# "Can't use function return value in write context" when using mysqli_num_rows()

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, authentication

I've been working on adding users to my database and I tried to do something to check if login is already occupied. If it's not, PHP should add the user to database, else give alert that login is already used. Here's my code:

```
<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'wiktor';
$password = 'wiktor';
$database = 'something';

$login = $_POST['login'];
$passwd = $_POST['pass'];
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$surname = $_POST['sur'];

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Error " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    echo "Connect success <br>";
}

$check = "select login from users where login = '$login'";
$test = $conn->query($check);

if(mysqli_num_rows($test) = 0){ 
    $sql = "insert into users 
    values (null,'$login','$passwd','$name','$surname')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Success";
    } else {
        echo "Error " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
} else {
    echo "The login is already in use!";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I'm getting "Can't use function return value in write context" on line

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($test) = 0)
```

which checks if there are any records with that login.

I used something similar before and it worked perfectly so what could be the problem now?

Comment: `if(mysqli_num_rows($test) =========== 0)`  ;)  Because you're mistakenly trying to assign 0 to that function

Comment: use == to compare  **if(mysqli_num_rows($test) == 0){**

Comment: Another little mistake I overlooked, damn, I need to pay more attention when coding. Thanks!

Comment: Dont use mysqli it's very old you should be using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this

```
 if(mysqli_num_rows($test) == 0)
```

Instead of,

```
 if(mysqli_num_rows($test) = 0)
```